# Why is the top-bar so inconsistent?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, user-interface, top-bar

For no discernable reason, at any given time I could be presented with any of:

- a [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) link, with badges indicating the size of the flag queue and the size of the review queue:

  [image: screenshot showing review link and badges for both flag- and review-queues]
- the same [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) link, but without a badge for the flag queue (even though it's certainly non-empty):

  [image: screenshot showing review link and badge for review queue only]
- a [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) link in place of the review one:

  [image: screenshot showing tools link and badge for review queue only]
- other variations on this theme that I can't recall/reproduce right now.

For the avoidance of doubt, all three of the above were taken within moments of eachother all whilst visiting the homepage.

What's going on?  Bug?  Surely this erratic behaviour is not by-design?

Comment: It's all intentional, just varying degrees of weird

Comment: Yeah, the Tools/Review swap is probably the worst of the lot. See [kiamlaluno's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152471/155160) on how it happens. The queue counts appear and disappear based on whether or not there's anything in the queue. That at least makes sense and isn't terribly obscure.

Comment: It used to be worse, with "blog" replacing "meta" every time a new article was posted. I think that was removed when the community bulletin was added.

Comment: If you object this behavior you can ask to change it; for example I would support asking to always show "review" even if your last visited tab was actually the Tools.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We changed this a while back...that was too confusing.

Though it'll still shift a bit as you get access to new things with more reputation, it'll always say "review" instead of *maybe* "tools" depending on what you visited last.

Comment: Hopefully this isn't a way to stack the analytics when you check back and see not many clicking the tools link any more

Comment: When you say it was changed "a while back", does that mean some time between the question being posed and your answer? It might be worth noting that the behaviour I cited arose mere minutes before I posted this question...

Comment: @eggyal - correct, it was between the two we just didn't update all the related meta questions.

Answer (score 7):

You will see *tools*, or *review* basing on the last tab you visited.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

The number you see to the left of *tools*, or *review* is the number of pending suggested edits.

When there are are suggested edits, and pending flags, the counters are shown this way (on Drupal Answers). The counter with the orange background is the suggested-edit counter, while the other is the flag counter.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the number of pending suggested edits is what I see *to the right* of tools/review; the number to the left (when it's there, which is not always) appears to be the number of *flags* pending review.

Comment: The number of pending suggested edits is the one on an orange background, such as in my screenshot; the number of flags is the one on a yellow background. Different sites probably use different colors for the background, though.

Comment: @kiamlaluno The flags on SO have orange background. Suggested edit background is more brown (pretty sure it's the same everywhere except here where it's black). But otherwise, yeah.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for this info.  It's pretty unintuitive, but it does seem to behave as you describe.  The only thing I don't understand is why the number of flags isn't appearing in my toolbar now, even though the queue has over a hundred items in it.  Any idea?

Comment: @eggyal After you visited `tools` and did something there, it doesn't nag you for a while. How long the while is, depends on how many flags there are, and possibly (I have the impression, but I'm not sure) on how much you did there.

Comment: Great, so this seems to explain *how* the behaviour arises.  Are you also saying that it's *intentional* by-design; or is it an oversight?  I'm not sure whether to leave this as an open bug, or submit a feature request.

Comment: @eggyal I think it is intentionally so.